# How to create this 4type or 3type tab list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I create the 4type or 3type tab list that are in this page - http://demos.brianmcculloh.com/swagger/ located in right side? I have seen that on many sites. Basically is there any free plugins, that would allow me to create something like this easily, or Will I need to make it by myself with show/hide functions, and how hard is it to make something like that? If there's already free plugin, then I need plugin, which is free for commercial use (allowed to be sold in marketplaces with ready blog/portfolio templates).

Comment: What do you mean by "4type or 3type tab list"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the 4type or 3type tab list,but for easy tabs,jquery-ui is fine
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/